# Por qué el resultado de mi consulta no es el esperado

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, mysqli

Estoy utilizando phpMyadmin, y la consulta es con estas 3 tablas

| material |
| --- |
| cod_material |
| descripcion |

| entradas | salidas |
| --- | --- |
| cod_entradas | cod_salidas |
| fecha_entra | fecha_sali |
| personal | personal_c |
| cod_materi | cod_material |
| cant_entra | cant_sale |

Tabla material con datos

| cod-material | descripcion |
| --- | --- |
| 22222 | Tubos 3m |
| 55555 | gabinetes |

tabla entradas con un registro

| cod_entradas | fecha_entra | personal | cod_materi | cant_entra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10000 | 20023-06-03 | Alejo | 22222 | 5 |

Realizo la siguiente consulta para que muestre el cod_material, descripcion, entrada,salida y stock, pero no se muestran los resultados.

```
`SELECT 
    material.cod_material,
    material.descripcion,
    SUM(entradas.cant_entra)AS entrada,
    SUM(salidas.cant_sale) AS salida,
    sum(entradas.cant_entra)-sum(salidas.cant_sale)As Stock
    FROM material
    JOIN entradas ON material.cod_material=entradas.cod_materi
    JOIN salidas ON material.cod_material=salidas.cod_material
    GROUP BY material.cod_material`
```

| cod_material | descripcion | entrada | salida | stock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |  |

Y de mostrarse quiero que aparezca en la salida 0 y en el stock 5,porque solo registre la entrada.

Ahora realizo el registro de una salida del mismo material.

| cod_salidas | fecha_sali | personal_c | cod_material | cant_sale |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10000 | 20023-06-04 | Aleidi | 22222 | 3 |

ejecuto la consulta anterior y esta vez si muestra lo que deseo, por el hecho de realizar las operaciones y que el stock sea lo esperado

| cod_material | descripcion | entrada | salida | stock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22222 | tubos 3m | 5 | 3 | 2 |

Ahora realizo otra entrada  del mismo material

| cod_entradas | fecha_entra | personal | cod_materi | cant_entra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | 20023-07-06 | Aleidi | 22222 | 6 |
| 10000 | 20023-06-03 | Alejo | 22222 | 5 |

Realizo la misma consulta

```
`SELECT 
    material.cod_material,
    material.des_material,
    SUM(entradas.cant_entra)AS entrada,
    SUM(salidas.cant_sale) AS salida,
    sum(entradas.cant_entra)-sum(salidas.cant_sale)As Stock
    FROM material
    JOIN entradas ON material.cod_material=entradas.cod_materi
    JOIN salidas ON material.cod_material=salidas.cod_material
    GROUP BY material.cod_material`
```

Y esta vez no me da el resultado esperado.

| cod_material | descripcion | entrada | salida | stock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22222 | tubos 3m | 11 | 6 | 5 |

La cantidad en la salida esta mal, porque no ingrese nada, deberia quedar en 3, y por lo tanto el stock no es el esperado.

ayuda, no sé que estoy haciendo mal, he intentado con otras consulta y no he podido solucionar.

Cabe destacar que realizo realizo estas consulta por separado y refleja la sumatoria correctamente

```
`SELECT 
    material.cod_material,
    material.des_material,
    SUM(entradas.cant_entra)AS entrada
    FROM material
    JOIN entradas ON material.cod_material=entradas.cod_materi
    GROUP BY material.cod_material`
```

| cod_material | descripcion | entrada |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 22222 | tubos 3m | 11 |

```
`SELECT 
    material.cod_material,
    material.des_material,
    SUM(salidas.cant_sale) AS salida
    FROM material
    JOIN salidas ON material.cod_material=salidas.cod_material
    GROUP BY material.cod_material`
```

| cod_material | descripcion | salida |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 22222 | tubos 3m | 3 |

Answer (score -1):

```
`SELECT P.*,
IFNULL(E.total_entradas, 0) entradas,
IFNULL(S.total_salidas, 0) salidas,
IFNULL(E.total_entradas, 0) - 
IFNULL(S.total_salidas, 0) stock
FROM material P
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT cod_materi, SUM(cantidad_entrada) 
total_entradas FROM entradas
GROUP BY cod_materi) E
ON P.cod_material = E.cod_materi
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT cod_materialpro, SUM(cantidad_salida) 
total_salidas FROM salidas
GROUP BY cod_materialpro) S
ON P.cod_material = S.cod_materialpro`
```

Esta consulta resolvio mis problemas

Comment: Si bien el resultado de la consulta es correcto, las respuestas que tienen solo código tienden a considerarse de baja calidad. Por favor agrega una explicación de cómo o por qué esto resuelve el problema planteado. Para más información lee [answer]. Un saludo.